# Using COMPASS for Responsive Website Design

Tags: html, ruby, sass, compass

I am trying to learn Responsive Website Design and I have already grasp the concept of Sass by compiling a `.scss file` to a `.css` file. Now I am trying to learn how to use `compass`.

I have already installed Ruby and Compass. I have created a new `compass project` in my folder.

[image: Using Compass]

[image: Inside the sassproject folder]

So now when I try to compile my `styles.scss` I get this error:

```
Change detected to: scss/styles.scss
error scss.styles.scss (Line 1: File to import not found or unreadable: compass/css3/images.)
Load path: D:/Demo/scss)
```

I'm trying to teach myself how to code. I know some HTML and CSS, but I would like to step up my game with Responsive Website Design. So I picked up this book to teach myself. [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/1783550236/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o01_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1783550236).

The codes in `styles.scss` as shown below when compiling:

```
@import "compass/css3/images";

header {
    @include background-image(linear-gradient(red, blue));
}

$brandBue: #416e8e;
.generic-Container {
    padding: 10px;
    border: $brandBlue 1px solid;
    background: #ccc;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(black, .3);
}

.box-customer-service {
    @extend .generic-container;
    padding: 25px;
}

*, *:before, *:after {
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(red, blue);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(red, blue);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(red, blue);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(red, blue);
    background-image: linear-gradient(red, blue);
}
```

If anybody could clarify on how to run compass with layman's term would be much appreciated. I am a noob but once I get the hang of it, it should be much easier for me to continue learning RWD.

Comment: FYI compass is deprecated and is no longer supported. It hasn't been updated for over 4 years. If you're trying to learn something you can use moving forward, you may want to pick something that is still supported. You might take a look at bourbon instead: https://www.bourbon.io/

Comment: @JayDorsey So instead of installing compass, I must install bourbon? Is Bourbon like the next Gem compass or whatever you call that? Sorry, correct me if I got the terms wrong.

Comment: Yes, you'd install bourbon instead. I'm not a heavy user of either, but I think they're relatively equivalent, except bourbon is maintained. It's a framework for writing sass that gives you some additional helpers. There's two additional products (neat & bitters) that give you other tools to make writing css easier. There's a number of tutorials for bourbon that are current & relevant. Here's one for example: https://www.sitepoint.com/getting-started-sass-bourbon/

Comment: JayDorsey, Okay, so I've installed bourbon, but now I am still scratching my head as to what to replace @import "compass/css3/images"; especially compass/css3/images. I've seen on 4-5+ year old YouTube videos that it works for past developers, but how can I apply this to today's standard with bourbon? I want to be able to move along in my book with Responsive Design. In my book it says "The installation of Compass is outside the scope of this book, so we're going to focus on the basic usage to deal with vendor prefixes and will assume that it is already installed on your machines."